# System error 1067 when shutting down Windows XP service from Python

Tags: python, windows, service, windows-xp

When I stop a WinXP service with `net stop [something]` from the command line, it stops without errors. However, when I do it with Python like this:

```
import subprocess
stop_args = ['net', 'stop', 'TagNet.OPC.DEP']
subprocess.check_call(stop_args)
```

I get the following error:

```
Service "TagNet.OPC.DEP" is stopping......
System error.
System error 1067
The process finished unexpectedly.
Service "TagNet.OPC.DEP" is successfully stopped.
```

Why do I get the `System error 1067`? How to shut down services gracefully from Python?

Comment: The service controller is setting the service exit status to `ERROR_PROCESS_ABORTED` (1067) because the service host process didn't update the status as stopped before exiting. You could instead try [`sc stop TagNet.OPC.DEP`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754599), but it will probably return the same exit code. You can handle the `subprocess.CalledProcessError` exception to ignore this error.  Check the exception's `returncode` and only `raise` the exception again if it's not `ERROR_PROCESS_ABORTED`.